# Dispatching Action inside Fetch

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, es6-promise

I am making an async call using fetch and then trying to set state by dispatching an action based on the result of the json data returned.

I am using a QR code reader to read a code which is passed to my didScan method.

```
    didScan(code) {
      if (this.state.showCamera){
       this.props.pushNewRoute('finder');
       getAppointment(code)
       .then((appointment)=>{
         if (appointment.valid){
           this.props.appointmentDetails(appointment);
           this.props.resetRoute('summary');
         }else{
           this.props.resetRoute('error');
         }
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         this.props.resetRoute('error');
       });
       this.setState({showCamera: false});
     }
   }
```

I am using react-redux to bind my actions to my dispatchers like this:

```
      function bindActions(dispatch){
      return {
          resetRoute:(route)=>dispatch(resetRoute(route)),
          pushNewRoute:(route)=>dispatch(pushNewRoute(route)),
          appointmentDetails:(details)=>dispatch(appointmentDetails(details))
      }
  }

  export default connect(null, bindActions)(Scanner);
```

but when the promise is returned by my getAppointment service it fails when it tries to do the routing.

```
this.props.resetRoute('summary');
```

The error is

> Possible unhandled promise rejection{id:0}
>   Reducers may not dispatch actions

None of my reducers dispatch any actions and the code works fine when I take it out of the Promise .then() block.

Here is the simple getAppointment fetch service for completeness:

```
export function getAppointment(id:string) {
  return fetch('http://myurl/' + id + '/')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    return error;
  });
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your syntax is for binding the actions, haven't seen it before. Here's a sample of code that I made for a project where I do a get request and then set the response as state:

**SearchBar.jsx** (this does a http request to Solr and gets a JSON object back, then sets that object as the state)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import httpClient from 'axios';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {setResponse} from '../actions/index'

class SearchBar extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
  }

  search() {
    let q = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
    httpClient(`/search?q=${q}`, { baseURL: window.location.href })
      .then( resp => {
        console.log(resp);
        this.props.setResponse(resp);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type='text' id='searchbar'/>
        <button onClick={this.search}>Search</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({setResponse: setResponse}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

This is the action:

```
export const setResponse = (res) => {
    return {
        type: 'RESPONSE_RECEIVED',
        payload: res
    }
};
```

This is the reducer:

```
export default function (state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'RESPONSE_RECEIVED':
            return action.payload;
            break;
    }
    return state;
}
```

Which is exported to a combining function (though there is only one reducer atm):

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import ResponseReducer from './reducer-response';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    response: ResponseReducer
});

export default allReducers;
```